# Weird HTML5 Worker JavaScript code (messages)

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, messaging, worker

https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder/blob/1c71ad46ab9088f92bc0a087dcb84df356b805f6/js/lib/recorderWorker.js

In lines 42 and 47 there are posted messages.

But these messages do not have a `command` field as required by the handlers in lines 5-23.

So I don't understand how these messages are handled. Please explain.

Comment: This isn’t the function that handles those messages. They aren’t handled at all in this code. The messages get sent to the main thread, not the worker itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are sent to the main thread, not the worker itself. They represent results. That function doesn’t handle any of those outgoing messages. It only handles *incoming* messages. That’s what a function listening for `message` events does.

For example:

```
// Main thread:
var worker = new Worker("recorderWorker.js");
worker.postMessage({
  command: "init", // This is where the command property is required.
  config: …
});
```